# Does this violate 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

$\int  dq / T$ of system +  $\int  dq / T$of surrounding >0 Should always be greater than 0 is the statement in my book for 2nd law of thermodynamics.

And that $\Delta S$ of system + $\Delta S$ of surrounding >0.

My question is:

If there is a container and adiabatic process is happening.Then  $\Delta S$ of system + $\Delta S$ of surrounding =0 since heat transfer will always be equal to 0.

Does it violate 2nd law only in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second law leads to (or can be stated)
$$
\Delta S_{\rm tot} \ge 0
$$
not $\Delta S_{\rm tot} > 0$ (where 'tot' refers to everything that undergoes some change during the given process). The result is zero for reversible processes, and greater than zero for irreversible processes. So the adiabatic process is allowed by the second law, and so is any other reversible process.

Having said that, the concept of a reversible process is an idealization. In practice there are no fully reversible processes, because of small amounts of friction and viscosity and things like that, or, for particles moving in vacuum, there are interactions such as the van der Waals interaction between ordinary bodies, and also gravitational effects. All these are hard to avoid completely, and their effects are tiny for many processes. However, tiny as they are, they usually prevent complete reversibility.

It is the standard practice in science to study idealized cases to begin with, so this should not be regarded as a problem with thermodynamic reasoning. Therefore it is perfectly sensible to study reversible processes as well as irreversible ones.

Answer (score 2):

The first term of your first equation only applies to the system for a reversible heat transfer  process and the inequality only applies to an irreversible process.

For the second equation the entropy of the surroundings can only change if there is heat transfer to or from the surroundings. Since there is no heat transfer in an adiabatic process $\Delta S_{surr}=0$.

But entropy can be generated in the system without heat transfer due to irreversible work. An example is the rapid expansion or compression of a gas by a piston in an insulated cylinder. For such a process $\Delta S_{sys}>0$. If the work is reversible then $\Delta S_{sys}=0$.

So the bottom line is $\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}≥0$ where the equality applies to a reversible process and the inequality applies to an irreversible process, and $\Delta S_{surr}=0$ for any adiabatic process.

Hope this helps.